# .net core visual studio publish is including runtimes

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

I'm currently using a .net core visual studio publish, and its including the runtime dlls in the output. I do not want these files, but would like to use the hosting bundles on the server.

This is a new thing, it didn't use to include these dlls with a publish. I think it might have been triggered by a visual studio update, but I am not positive why its happening.

Here's my settings:

[image]

The Deployment Mode is not set to "Self-Contained" which I think is the setting that should force the runtime to be included.

I've done tons of googling but can't seem to find any other configuration that would be related to this. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There seems to be no clear documentation, but when you choose Portable as Target Runtime, the wizard would try to generate binaries for Azure App Service, instead of "the host bundles". Thus, don't use an option before truly understand it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I can look into that setting if you think it might be the issue. I am confident I haven't changed it though, and I did try a couple of the other choices. win-86 and win-64. I get an error that the framework-dependent application host requires a target framework of at least netcoreapp2.1, Im only on 2.0. Maybe that changed recently.

Comment: .NET Core 2.0 expires on Oct 1, so you shouldn't target it any more. Use 2.1 as early as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Posting an answer, just in case anyone else ends up here. I found the answer mostly because of Lex Li comment.

The most recent upgrade to visual studio / .net core seems to require you to specificity a target runtime in your Publish Profile. In order to make this work, you will be forced to upgrade your project to 2.1 or higher. Otherwise visual studio will choose portable by default, and include the runtime dlls in the publish.